# R TM package produces strange results with Inspect command

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I'm having a little trouble with the *inspect* function from the *tm* package in R.

I have a sample 2-row data.table as defined below:

```
dt <- data.table(doc_id = c(1, 2), text = c('the driver of the 1st vehicle', 'the light turned red'))
```

I create a corpus and inspect per the package documentation:

```
corp <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(dt)))
inspect(corp)
```

The output looks very strange:

```
<VECSXP 0x1de5597db50>
  <VECSXP 0x1de5307d800>
    <VECSXP 0x1de5307d6c0>
      <STRSXP 0x1dd62b83b80>
        <CHARSXP 0x1de52b7f7e0>
        attributes: 
          <CHARSXP 0x1db146237a0>
          attributes: 
            <CHARSXP 0x1d342737728>
      <VECSXP 0x1de57fa88c0>
        <STRSXP 0x1dd728dc0a8>
        <VECSXP 0x1de57ab02a0>
          <REALSXP 0x1dd62b73198>
          <INTSXP 0x1dd62b731d0>
```

The output goes on and on like this and doesn't make sense.  It doesn't look like what should be printed based on the package vignette.  I'd appreciate any help with making this work!

System info:  R 3.6.3, Windows machine, tm_0.7-7.

Comment: Can't replicate. Results look as expected on my machine. But I'm using R 4.0x and tm 07-8.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out I had a different package loaded with an *inspect* function.  When I sourced inspect from *tm*, that fixed the problem.  Thanks for looking!